# How to render bundle item product name with From/To: bundle product prices in price.phtml

Tags: catalog, template, performance, bundled-product

I have many bundle products that are made up of bundle items.

For example if I have a bundle product called "Farm Animals" made up of four bundle items:

duck - $1
chicken - $2
cow - $3
zebra - $4

I would like to display the following pricing information:

```
Farm Animals
From: 1$ duck To: $4 zebra
```

At the moment I've implemented:

```
            $selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
                $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product), $_product
            );

            $max_prod_name = '';
            $min_prod_name ='';
            $max_price = 0;
            $min_price = 999999;

            foreach($selectionCollection as $option) {
                $pr = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($option->product_id);
                if ($pr->getPrice() > $max_prod_name) {
                    $max_price = $pr->getPrice();
                    $max_prod_name = $pr->name;
                } else if ($pr->getPrice() < $min_price) {
                    $min_price = $pr->getPrice();
                    $min_prod_name = $pr->name;
                }
            }
```

This is very resource intensive when rendering category list pages with the foreach loop executing multiple times per product.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to avoid the extra load() within the loop.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();

$selectionCollection = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
    $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($_product), $_product
);

$max_prod_name = '';
$min_prod_name ='';
$max_price = 0;
$min_price = 999999;

foreach ($selectionCollection as $option) {
    $price = $option->getPrice();
    if ($price > $max_price) {
        $max_price = $price;
        $max_prod_name = $option->getName();
    } else if ($price < $min_price) {
        $min_price = $price;
        $min_prod_name = $option->getName();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All this data is already present in the tables `catalog_product_bundle_selection` and the `catalog_product_flat`. I guess the easiest way to go about is getting a collection via `Mage::getModel('catalog/product->getCollection()` and joining that with the `catalog_product_bundle_selection` table.

So where `catalog_product_bundle_selection` fields `parent_product_id` is your bundled product and the `product_id` equals the `entity_id` in the `catalog_product_flat` table. Then retrieve the `name`, `price`, `special_price` and `special_price_from` and `special_price_to` fields to determine the products current price. Once you have all of this you can determine what is the minimum and maximum prices.

Now I've never done this so I don't have any ready to go code lying around for you but if you manage to get this to work please let me know and maybe post some code. If you need any more help let me know.